# How to encode person names for use in XGBoost?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, xgboost

I appreciate the help. Googling for how to use string features with XGBoost mainly returns results for categorical variables, which I think is different from what I am doing. I am trying to use XGBoost to predict race from first name and last name. What I want to do is character-encode my names, similar to what I am doing for an LSTM in Pytorch. There, I use this function

```py
def encode_name(name: str) -> torch.Tensor:
   return torch.tensor(
       [VALID_NAME_CHARS_DICT[char] for char in name], device=DEVICE
   )
```

How would I do something similar for XGBoost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XGBoost only accepts numerical values, so you'll have to convert your text to an array. This can be done using methods such as tokenizaton or TFIDF. Here's an example of both, using Hugging Face Tokenizers and `TfidfVectorizer`

```py
# Hugging Face Tokenizers
from tokenizers import ByteLevelBPETokenizer

tokenizer = ByteLevelBPETokenizer()

# Training the tokenizer
tokenizer.train_from_iterator(["Some text data", "Some more text data"])

# Encoding the text
encoded_text = tokenizer.encode("Some text data")
print(encoded_text.ids)

# The output would be an array of numbers representing the text

# Tfidf Vectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

# Creating the vectorizer
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()

# Fitting the vectorizer to the text data
x = vectorizer.fit_transform(["Some text data", "Some more text data"])

# The output of x.toarray() would be a numerical representation of the text data
print(x.toarray())
```

Output:

```py
[264, 266, 265]
[[0.57735027 0.         0.57735027 0.57735027]
 [0.44832087 0.63009934 0.44832087 0.44832087]]
```

However, I would not recommend this. XGBoost is not made to handle textual data. For this task, you can use a neural network architecture specifically built for sequence data, such as Long Short Term Memory (LSTM), Gated Recurrent Unit (GRU), or Transformer models. These models are designed to handle the sequential nature of text data and can provide better performance in tasks like sentiment analysis, text classification, language translation and more. In your case, it's text classification.

Typically with a neural network such a Transformer (https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.03762), you'd encode your text using byte level BPE, apply positional encoding and then embed your text.

Comment: Thanks for the example! I am using an LSTM model as well, but it is not performing as expected, so I wanted to benchmark it against XGBoost, which has been used by other people working on the same problem.